# Limit of integral sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

I am asked to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(n^4\cos t)dt=0$$
I think you have to calculate
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}\sin(n^4\cos t)dt$$
and
$$\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(n^4\cos t)dt$$
So that you can somehow integrate the second one by parts, but I can't quite figure out how.

Comment: Riemann Lebesgue lemma is the key here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\left(m\cos t\right)\,dt \stackrel{t\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-t}{=}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(m\sin t)\,dt\stackrel{t\mapsto\arcsin u}{=}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(mu)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du$$
and now we may invoke the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).
Since $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du$ is finite, the limit of the LHS as $m\to +\infty$ is zero. 
The LHS actually is $\frac{\pi}{2} H_0(m)$, with $H_0$ being a [Struve function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).